# Getting configured Pop-up in ArcGIS Pro to publish to Portal

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I am using ArcGIS Pro version 2.5. From the pictures below, I have the pop-up configured and it displays correctly in ArcGIS Pro.

[image: Popup Configuration]

[image: Popup]

I have read that you can publish layers and the configured pop-ups will follow to Portal which my version is 10.7.1.

- https://community.esri.com/thread/246120-pop-up-created-in-pro-does-not-work-when-published-to-portal
- https://community.esri.com/thread/212571-how-do-you-display-popups-configured-in-pro-with-expressions-to-display-correctly-in-a-webmap

My workflow is like the first post's for publishing.  Share tab -- Publish web layer -- I am referencing registered data -- Publishing both Feature and Map Image.  I do not have version issues like the second post with my Portal being above 10.6.

After the publish goes though, when I open the web map and load the data in, none of the pop-up configuration transfers.  The custom text, selection of fields, and expressions do not publish.  I have tried this with the image layer, the feature layer, registered data, and hosted data.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was found to be caused when publishing directly to an ArcGIS server and not when publishing to the Portal.